# Keras Dense Layer Error: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I'm trying to visualize the output of each convolutional layer in keras, following this link: [MNIST Visualisation](https://github.com/julienr/ipynb_playground/blob/master/keras/convmnist/keras_cnn_mnist.ipynb). I have modified some layers to remove errors, but now I'm stuck with the Dense Layer Error.

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=5, suppress=True)
np.random.seed(1337) # for reproducibility

nb_classes = 10

# the data, shuffled and split between tran and test sets
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data("mnist.pkl")

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_train = X_train.astype("float32")
X_test = X_test.astype("float32")
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

i = 4600
pl.imshow(X_train[i, 0], interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.binary)
print("label : ", Y_train[i,:])

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',input_shape = (1,28,28))) #changed border_mode from full -> valid
convout1 = Activation('relu')
model.add(convout1)
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 32, 3))

convout2 = Activation('relu')
model.add(convout2)
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(32*196, 128)) #ERROR HERE
```

Any comment or suggestion highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation of a [`Dense`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense) layer then you'll notice that the first argument it accepts is the shape of output and second is `init` which describes the way how weights of the layer are initiated. In your case you provided the `int` as second positional argument and this caused error. You should change the code to (assuming that you want an output in a form of 128-dimensional vector):

```
model.add(Dense(128))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Marcin, I changed it to model.add(Dense(128)), but I received "OverflowError: Range exceeds valid bounds" error. Do you perhaps know why?

Comment: the line that has the error. I changed it from model.add(Dense(32*196, 128))  to model.add(Dense(128))

Comment: Marcin, in addition to your code, I need to add "from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')" and change the order of input_shape = (28,28,1) instead of (1,28,28). So, your answer does work - Thank you :)